# How do I count duplicates in a column, and then sum up the values attached to those duplicates

Tags: excel-formula

I want to remove duplicates and concatenate the values attached to them but I can't figure it out. Take this example data set:

```
Column A       Column B       Column C        Column D
Example 1-a      5              Example 1       13
Example 1-a      2              Example 2       8
Example 1-b      4              Example 3       2
Example 1-c      2
Example 2-a      2
Example 2-b      4
Example 2-b      0
Example 3-a      2
```

What I have is the left, and what I want is on the right. I was able to remove duplicates but using `countif(A:A,A2)` and created column C with `Left(A2,9)`, but I can't figure out how to sum up the corresponding values.
How do I do this without any coding since I don't know macros. I only know how to use formulas.

Comment: How is `Example 2` yielding a value of `8`? shouldn't it be `6`?

Answer (score 0):

In cell `D2`, type the following formula and drag down:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((C1=LEFT(A$1:A$8,9))*(B$1:B$8))
```

[image]